# How to set a flag every clock cycle in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I need to increase my counter each clock cycle, and the first idea I had was to set a flag count<='1' each clock cycle and then in the counter process add 1 in my register.
It should be done like this?

```
 begin
   count<='1';
   wait for -- ns;
   count<='0';
   wait for -- ns;
 end process;
```

Is there a smart solution?

Comment: Do you plan to synthesize this code? Please [edit] your question and show us the code with the counter. Why don't you simply add "1" to the counter on every clock edge?

Comment: Can you be a little clearer? Counters operate on a single clock edge. In hardware using a latch an increment by one provides inherent delay and at least one 'bit' inverttng creating a gated oscillator. We typically model clocks in testbenches with relaxation oscillators like your not quite complete process statement.  Delays don't synthesize. There's an RTL Synthesis subset of VHDL described in the now withdrawn IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 or your synthesis vendor documentation. For Vivado that would UG901.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will not pass synthesis.

If this is for a testbench in which you emulate an input signal you can do something like this

```
count <= not count after period ns;
```

where 'period' represents the rising edge of the internal clock

If you are trying to synthesize this code you will need to include a clock for the process

```
process ( internal_clk )
begin
        if ( rising_edge ( internal_clk ) ) then
                count <= not count;
        end if;
end process;
```

If ultimately you are trying to just increment a counter why not increment the counter directly?

```
process ( internal_clk )
begin
        if ( rising_edge ( internal_clk ) ) then
                counter <= counter + 1;
                if ( counter = max_counter ) then
                        counter <= 0;
                end if;
        end if;
end process;
```

Just remember doing this will result in a delay of a single clock cycle since these registers will only update every rising edge of the clock.